# Connecting to SQL-Azure in rails using tiny_TDS: [BUG] Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, azure-sql-database, tiny-tds

We're trying to get rails to talk to a sqlserver db on Azure, we install freeTDS with openssl and libiconv:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-libiconv-prefix=DIR --with-openssl=DIR
make
make install
```

We then add tiny_TDS and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter to the gemfile:

```
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'

$ bundle install
```

Configure the database:

```
development:  
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: xxxxxxx.database.windows.net
  mode: DBLIB
  port: 1433
  database: xxxxx
  username: xxxxxxxx
  password: x
  azure: true
```

Run the server:

```
$ rails s
```

Everything works great up until this point, but as soon as you visit the site ruby crashes.

```
steven@jenny:~/irr$ rails server -p 3001
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3001
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-07-24 15:37:00] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-07-24 15:37:00] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2012-02-14) [x86_64-linux]
[2012-07-24 15:37:00] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=7586 port=3001
/home/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/tiny_tds-0.5.1/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:68: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p318 (2012-02-14 revision 34678) [x86_64-linux]

-- control frame ----------
c:0048 p:---- s:0232 b:0232 l:000231 d:000231 CFUNC  :connect
c:0047 p:0429 s:0228 b:0228 l:000227 d:000227 METHOD /home/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/tiny_tds-0.5.1/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:68
```

We've tried several versions of ruby: 1.9.2-p318, 1.9.2-p320, 1.9.3-p125. Same error with all of them.

This is on ubuntu 11.10 using rvm and FreeTDS-0.9.1.

Any Ideas on a workaround?

Have I made an error somewhere along the way?

#### Edit

Output from IRB:

```
require 'tiny_tds'
client = TinyTds::Client.new(:username =>'XXXXX@XXXXXXX.database.windows.net', :password => 'XXXXXXX', :host => 'XXXXXX.database.windows.net',  :mode => 'DBLIB', :azure => 'true')
SystemStackError: stack level too deep from /home/martinr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80
Maybe IRB bug!!
```

It seems to be a bug with ruby itself:

```
/home/martinr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/tiny_tds-0.5.1/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:68: [BUG] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be caused by having a username `username@servername`

When you remove the `@severname` part, ruby no longer crashes

Answer (score 2):

You should just do a simple IRB prompt and do something like this mentioned on the TinyTDS read me.

`require 'tiny_tds'
client = TinyTds::Client.new(...)`

Fill in your connection params. Simple stuff like username, password, and host. Let me know how things go.

- https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Using-Azure
- https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds#using-tinytds-with-azure

Comment: Thanks for the response, added output from IRB to question.

Comment: I've got it working with sqlserver on another machine, it just seems to be when trying to connect to azure. The password for sql-azure has special characters like "*%^$)", I've got a feeling that this could be causing the issue. I'm in the process of trying to get the db admin to change the password to something with fewer special characters to test the theory out.

Comment: @Martinffx Does passwords like "*%^$)" are really problematic ? because i am also getting similar errors ..