# tiny_tds: Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure-sql-database, irb, tiny-tds

This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632743/connecting-to-sql-azure-in-rails-using-tiny-tds-bug-segmentation-fault). However, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11720942/251096) posted on that question, didn't work for me. I have installed freetds on my Mac. I have specified the following in my GemFile.

```
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 4.1.0'
```

And I can connect to Azure SQL **successfully** using the following,

```
tsql -H host_name.database.windows.net -U user_name -D database_name -p 1433 -P password
```

I can also connect to Azure SQL **successfully** at irb.

```
require 'tiny_tds'
client = TinyTds::Client.new(:username => 'user_name@host_name', :password => 'password', :host =>'host_name.database.windows.net')
```

But when I run,
rake db:migrate
I get the following error,

```
[BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x007fff5f3ffff8
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
```

It is then followed by,

```
Control frame information
C level backtrace information
Other runtime information
```

Finally, ending with,

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

Can anyone please share any ideas or suggestions?

Update: My Database.yml looks like,

```
development:
  #adapter: sqlite3
  #database: db/development.sqlite3
  #pool: 5
  #timeout: 5000
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: dblib
  dataserver:
  host: host_name.database.windows.net
  port: 1433
  database: database_name
  username: user_name
  password: password
  timeout: 5000
  azure: true
```

I ran the following at IRB,

```
2.1.1 :028 > ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
2.1.1 :029 >        :adapter  => "sqlserver",
2.1.1 :030 >        :host     => "host_name.database.windows.net",
2.1.1 :031 >        :username => "user_name",
2.1.1 :032 >        :password => "password",
2.1.1 :033 >        :database => "database_name"
2.1.1 :034?>    )
```

and got the following response,

```
 => #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x00000101e8c798 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x00000101e8c748>, @spec=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionSpecification:0x00000101f3ceb8 @config={:adapter=>"sqlserver", :host=>"host_name.database.windows.net", :username=>"user_name", :password=>"password", :database=>"database_name"}, @adapter_method="sqlserver_connection">, @checkout_timeout=5, @dead_connection_timeout=5, @reaper=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool::Reaper:0x00000101e8c720 @pool=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x00000101e8c798 ...>, @frequency=nil>, @size=5, @reserved_connections=#<ThreadSafe::Cache:0x00000101e8c6d0 @backend={}, @default_proc=nil>, @connections=[], @automatic_reconnect=true, @available=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool::Queue:0x00000101e8c658 @lock=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x00000101e8c798 ...>, @cond=#<MonitorMixin::ConditionVariable:0x00000101e8c630 @monitor=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x00000101e8c798 ...>, @cond=#<Thread::ConditionVariable:0x00000101e8c608>>, @num_waiting=0, @queue=[]>>
```

Comment: whats your database.yml file look like?

Comment: @blotto I have updated my question with database.yml.

Comment: Retry the Ruby things you have done using `rails c` rather than `irb`.  Ruby with the Rails environment loaded is a much more complex beast and Ruby alone. NB I ran into a similar problem that turned out to be a name conflict between native libs.  This ought to be deducible from the backtrace, if it's the problem.

Comment: @Indrajeet I'm also facing the exact same issue. How did you resolved? Since it is quite old post I guess you would have resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify your database.yml config, strip down to bare essentials.

```
development:
 adapter: sqlserver
 host: "host.database.windows.net"
 port: 1433
 database: <database>
 username: <username>
 password: <password>
 timeout: 5000
```

But first try to emulate the connection instance that would happen through the db:migrate task in the IRB as such.

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
   :adapter  => "sqlserver",
   :host     => "host.database.windows.net",
   :username => <username>,
   :password => <password>,
   :database => <database>
 )
```

If that is successfull, then use just those values in your database.yml.  If you need to add more config values, add one at a time.  Though these core configs should do the job.

Comment: I emulated the connection instance in IRB and updated my question with the response. Is there a way to deduce from the response, if the connection instance is successful.

Comment: the instance you posted looks successfull.  have you trimmed the database.yml configs down to just those values? comment out all the other ones. are try db:migrate again

Comment: I get this error when I try db:migrate, ----->
rake aborted!
TinyTds::Error: USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different Database.